# Different light source settings when linking

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, linked-data

I`ve been working with diferent scenes. Im working on a certain animation with eevee and i have a problem with linked light source (sun). The linked sun resets its shadow bias values to one making shadows less sharp and less precise.

[image: image here]

Comment: Hello :). There used to be some limits on linked lights between scenes (maybe there still are). What Blender version are you using?

Comment: Hi! Im using blender 2.9